# python-for-list index out of range

Tags: python

I am a beginner of Python. Could someone point out why it keeps saying

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/practice example/datascraper templates.py", line 21, in <module>
    print findPatTitle[i]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Thanks a lot.

Here are the codes:

```
from urllib import urlopen
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import re

webpage=urlopen('http://www.voxeu.org/').read()

patFinderTitle=re.compile('<title>(.*)</title>')      ##title tag
patFinderLink=re.compile('<link rel.*href="(.*)"/>')  ##link tag

findPatTitle=re.findall(patFinderTitle,webpage)
findPatLink=re.findall(patFinderLink,webpage)

listIterator=[]
listIterator=range(2,16)

for i in listIterator:
    print findPatTitle[i]
    print findPatLink[i]
    print '/n'
```

Comment: Do you have some prior knowledge of the page?  Why are you looking for that specific range of results from the two lists ?

Comment: The *real* answer here is: [**Don't parse HTML with regexes!**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: What is the value of i when it gets the error and how many entries in the lists? Apart from the don't use regex for HTML - why have you hard coded 2 and 16 and not just taken the length of the lists?

Comment: You're even importing `BeautifulSoup` already! *Use it!*

Answer (score 2):

The error message is perfectly descriptive.

You're trying to access a hard-coded range of indices (2,16) into `findPatTitle`, but you have no idea how many items there are.

When you want to iterate over multiple similar collections simultaneously, use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip).

```
for title, link in zip(findPatTitle,  findPatLink):
    print 'Title={0} Link={1}'.format(title, link)
```

Comment: there is only one element in `findPatTitle`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham In one isolated test case? `re.findall` returns "all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings."

Comment: I just mean in his example, I printed his list there is actually nothing in it, his regex is finding nothing.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Right, but that's based on some external input (the content of that web page). Who writes programs based on some fixed input? What would the point of the program be? The point of my answer is to show how to do this correctly, regardless of inputs. You know what they say happens when you *assume*.

Comment: yep, I totally understand. I just mentioned it as I thought it was worth pointing out that using regex was also not a very good idea.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have a different number of results than you expected. Don't hard-code that. But let's also rewrite this to be a bit more pythonic:

Replace this:

```
listIterator=[]
listIterator=range(2,16)

for i in listIterator:
    print findPatTitle[i]
    print findPatLink[i]
    print '/n'
```

with the two lists [zipped](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) together:

```
for title, link in zip(findPatTitle, findPatLink):
    print title
    print link
    print '/n'
```

This will loop over both at once, however long the list is. 1 element or 100 elements, it makes no difference.

Comment: Thanks for all the discussions and solutions. I actually have no coding experiences before (except for Matlab). What is the efficient way to learn data scraping.